# How to find polynomials satisfying a given ideal of relations

Tags: polynomials, commutative-algebra, ideals, groebner-basis

I have come across results/algorithms on how, given a set of polynomials in $k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ ($k$ a field) to find the ideal of relations. E.g. $k[a^2,ab,c^2] \cong k[x,y,z]/(xy-z^2)$

I am interested in going backwards, given an ideal (of relations) $I$ and $A=k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]/I$, is there an nice/good way of finding polynomials $P_i(x_1\ldots,x_n)$ in $A$ so that $I$ is their ideal of relations is $I$. e.g. in $k[x_1,\ldots,x_5]/(x_1x_2x_3-x_3x_4^{2}-x_5^2) \cong k[P_1,\ldots,P_5]$

Of course I suppose you can just write down $P_i(x_j) = \sum_n c_{i,n} \prod x_j^{e_j}$ and equate them and try to solve for coefficients and see if there is a solution, but that seems very inefficient, and really a pain to do by hand for my example in $5$ variables when the ideal is not monomial.

Another way of asking: (I just found out while writing this question): one can use Grobner bases to find the ideal defining the relations between given polynomials. The questions is can that process be reversed?

Comment: It's unclear to me what you're looking for. Do you want $k[P_1,\dots,P_n]$ to be a subring of a polynomial ring, like $k[a^2,ab,b^2]$?

Comment: Yes, $k[P_1,\ldots,P_n]$ is in $k[x_1,\ldots,x_5]$

Comment: Is this not only possible when the variety can be parameterized (is unirational)? Your example of the cone (or conic section if you think projectively) is the parameterization $x\mapsto a^2, y\mapsto b^2, z\mapsto ab$. Now, I don't know whether a cubic hypersurface of ${\Bbb A}^5$ (a 4-fold) is unirational. A google search gave [Mijatovic's bachelor thesis](http://www.math.uni-bonn.de/people/huybrech/Mijatovicfinal.pdf) and [Gammelgaard's masters thesis](https://www.duo.uio.no/bitstream/handle/10852/64114/SorenGammelgaard-thesis-final.pdf).

Comment: Thanks, I guess the question was more subtle than I thought.